# Performance of vector and array in Clojure

Tags: performance, clojure

I am trying to solve the [Maximum subarray problem on hacker rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maxsubarray). This is a standard DP problem and I write an O(n) solution:

```
(defn dp
  [v]
  (let [n (count v)]
    (loop [i 1 f (v 0) best f]
      (if (< i n) 
        (let [fi (max (v i) (+ f (v i)))]
          (recur (inc i) fi (max fi best)))
        best))))


(defn positive-only
  [v]
  (reduce + (filterv #(> % 0) v)))


(defn line->ints
  [line]
  (->> 
   (clojure.string/split line #" ")
   (map #(Integer. %))
   (into [])
   ))


(let [T (Integer. (read-line))]
  (loop [test 0]
    (when (< test T)
      (let [_ (read-line)
            x (read-line)
            v (line->ints x)
            a (dp-array v)
            b (let [p (positive-only v)]
                (if (= p 0) (reduce max v) p))]
        (printf "%d %d\n" a b))
      (recur (inc test)))))
```

To my surprise, I got time-limited-exceed for a large test case. I downloaded the input file, and found that the above version needs about 3 seconds to run.

I thought the bottleneck is in `(v i)` (getting the i-th element in vector v). So I changed the data structure from vector to an array:

```
(defn dp-array
  [v0]
  (let [v (into-array v0)
        n (int (alength v))]
    (loop [i 1
           f (aget v 0)
           best f]
      (if (< i n) 
        (let [fi (max (aget v i) (+ f (aget v i)))]
          (recur (inc i) fi (max fi best)))
        best))))
```

This array version is even slower. On the same input, it costs 33 seconds, much slower than the vector version. I think the slowness is due to boxing and unboxing. I tried to add type hints, but encountered run-time errors. Could anyone help me improve `dp-array` function? Thanks!

Also, great appreciate if anyone knows how to improve the vector version.

**UPDATE:**

Finally I managed to get my clojure program accepted, not by optimizing over the dynamic programming function, but by changing `(Integer. str)` to `(Integer/parseInt str)`. In this way, reflection is avoided in converting from string to integer.

I also replace `into-array` by `int-array`. But the speed of both versions are still on par with each other. I would expect the array version be faster than the vector version.

Comment: a better definition for positive-only: `#(apply + (filter pos? %))`

Comment: You may see better performance from `dp-array` if you explicitly make an `int-array` for v, otherwise you'll end up with boxed and generic math that could be specialized for int.

Comment: I suspect your problem is with reflection, not with boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @Alex if the array isn't hinted, you'll see both reflection and boxing/unboxing, and the fix for reflection also fixes the boxing issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Clojure compiler can't infer the type of `v` in the array version of the `dp-array` function whose argument v0 has unknown type. This causes costs to reflections when evaluating the following `alength` and `aget`.  In order to avoid these unnecessary reflections, you have to replace `into-array` with `long-array`.